# can you run 2 versions of Java in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, java

I have a website that I need to run an older version of Java then what I currently run.

How can I have 2 versions of Java on my windows 7 system?

Comment: "How can I have 2 versions of Java on my windows 7 system?" - Java installations are separate, so Java 7 and Java 8 installations, having two different versions of Java 7/8 is possible but more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply go to the Java website and find archived versions, find the one you need (you may need to create a java account to access downloads) and download and install it. However, every time you try and update your day to day java (the latest version) it will always ask you to delete the old version, simply select no. I currently have Java 8 and 7 on the same machine and it works perfectly. If you need more specifics I might be able to help you out!